# xml layout visibly different to code generated layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-gridview

Items will be displayed in a `GridView`:

```
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/month_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_half_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_half_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:horizontalSpacing="4dp"
    android:verticalSpacing="4dp"/>
```

The layout for the items used to be generated in code:

```
private LinearLayout getMonthImageView() {
    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(context);
    layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    TextView text = new TextView(context);
    text.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    text.setSingleLine();
    layout.addView(text, 0);

    ImageView image = new ImageView(context);
    image.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
    image.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
    layout.addView(image, 1);

    return layout;
}
```

I've refactored that part to come from an xml layout file instead:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/month_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:singleLine="true"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/month_icon"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

This had an unwanted visible effect: the gap between the items in the `GridView` has grown larger, as if the items had acquired some padding or margin (which is clearly not the case). Why is that? What is the difference of the items being generated in code versus coming from an xml layout file? How can I make the items scale up again?

Before (code layout):
[image]

After (xml layout):
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I see some potential issues, but it's hard for me to say exactly what, without an image description of your problem.
You might wanna check out these few things:

1. If you're inflating `LinearLayout`, you should probably avoid `android:layout_height="match_parent"`, because it takes up maximum space (usually the whole screen) even though you might not need it.
2. I'm thinking `ImageView` probably shouldn't be equal to parent, but have a distinct size.
   This way also, it takes up maximum space in its parent, which it might not need.

My advice is, try a `RelativeLayout`, with the `android:layout_width="match_parent"` and `android:layout_height="wrap_content`.

Then use different `layout_align` options to align everything on top, and give some specific dimensions to your `ImageView`.

That's just my guess, I might be wrong though.

Comment: Hm.. that doesn't really address the problem I'm having. I don't want to change the Layout class. What I want to know is: why is there a difference whether the layout comes from code or xml?

Comment: I've added some pictures though.